# Подписание файла ЭЦП на c++

Tags: c++

Мне нужно на c++ создать следующее приложение:

1. Приложение читает данные из файла, указанного при запуске или запрошенного от пользователя .
2. Проверяет наличие цифровой подписи этого файла данных.
3. О наличии/ отсутствии подписи сообщает.
4. Предлагает убрать/добавить подпись.
5. Результат писать в другой файл. Имя его получать при запуске  или формировать автоматически.

Я понимаю как алгоритмически создавать подпись, но не понимаю как подписать файл или сделать проверку уже существующей подписи

Comment: Подпись своя или по ГОСТу?

Comment: Своя, банальной хэш-функцией сделанная.

Comment: Насколько банальной? Если какое простенькое CRC32, то легко подбирается так, чтоб получалось на выходе для всего файла какое-то предопределенное значение, и если оно получается — считать файл подписанным.

Comment: тут нужно знать формат файла. с "по ГОСТУ" всё понятно - там PKCS#7 , например присоединенная (*.sig).
без формата не разберешь где конец файла и начало подписи